# jspInit keeps object in memory for all browser requests

Tags: java, jsp

My jsp web application takes input from html input and keep it in the memory with the press of the button, so actually i push the values in the memory and keeps it untill reset is pressed.
The problem comes when i goto another machine and run that application, i get the same values that were entered by the previous user.

eg:

main.jsp has some input fields and when i click 'add' those values from html input is stored in memory objects, and is showed in the html inputs till the memory is not cleared.

Now from another machine, i access this application and go to jsp file, there i get prefilled html input boxes having same values.

I know it is caused by i initializing the class object inside jspInit() function.

I have made sample project to show you the problem.

> Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ page import="test.TestClass" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%!
TestClass objTest;
public void jspInit()
{
    objTest = new TestClass();
 }
%>
<form action="Test.jsp">
value1: <input type="text" name="txtValue1" value="    <%out.print(objTest.value1);%>"/>
value2: <input type="text" name="txtValue2" value="    <%out.print(objTest.value2);%>"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

<%
if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit")!=null)
{
    String str1 = request.getParameter("txtValue1");
    String str2 = request.getParameter("txtValue2");
    objTest.add(str1, str2);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

> TestClass.java

```
package test;

public class TestClass {

    public String value1 ="no value";
    public String value2 ="no value";
    public void add(String str1, String str2)
    {
        value1 = str1;
        value2 = str2;
    }
}
```

why am i not getting a new page everytime i go from a different machine.The **jspInit()** function makes the object static and all its values are retained.

I need this **jspInit() function** because i want to retain the values for that particular user so that when he refreshes the page the form values are not gone.

How can i make jspInit() to retain value only for that particular browser 
request. Also what other approaches i can use.

Also the actual application is very big, so if possible please suggest some workaround for this approach.

P.S: A newbie to jsp.

P.S: I know using scriptlets is not a good approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The jspInit method is common for all the threads of your servlet class. Its use is basically for getting database connections and reader writer objects for a common resource. Your requirement is for every individual client of your server (i.e. different machine), for this you must use session object to store the parameters or use a Java Bean object.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464166/jsp-and-servlet-life-cycle-method) for good knowledge.

Comment: will the java bean object be available to the Jsp when we refresh the page. Means if i store some value in java bean object and then go to another page and come back to this one, or just refreshes the page, will it retain the values i stored earlier?

Comment: You have to store that bean object in session to use throughout the application flow. you can accept the answer if it helped..

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to use the `session` Object to store values related to each session.

You can add session attributes like this:  `session.setAttribute("IDxxx",1)` and you can retrieve Objects from session like this `int id= Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("IDxxx").toString())`

For more on jsp implicit Objects see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) and [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1009)