# Does jspInit() run only once?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, hsqldb, init

I need to open a connection pool in a tomcat servlet. In my jsp page I overwrite `jspInit()`

```
<%!
public void jspInit() {
. . .
}
%>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but i'm not sure if this is the correct way to initialize a connection pool. Does this jspInit() execute only once, i.e. when the very first user open this jsp page ?

My point is: when the second and the third etc. user opens the same `.jsp` page, this  `jspInit()` get ignored as if it was not there at all ?  So for the 2nd, 3rd, . . . users this `jsp` page does not have the `jspInit()` method executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats correct. Its called only once by the container
 during the lifecycle. Hence this method will be perfect for creating/opening a connection

Ref : http://www.coderanch.com/t/425072/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/JSP

Comment: Any resources confirming that?

Comment: Thank you, so `public void jspInit()` is the best place to open a conenction

Comment: @Pshemo Edited my answer to add the resource

Comment: @Rehman I mean official resource. I may be wrong since my knowledge about JEE may be outdated but from what I remember one of reasons `init` was introduced to `Servlets` (and JSP are converted to servlets) was to let container reuse servlet objects. It simply calls `destroy()` when want to *unregister* them, and `init()` when register them again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464166/jsp-and-servlet-life-cycle-method - will it be enough ?